# how to avoid space between particular words while using split() in python

Tags: python

I am using `split()` to convert my string into list but I found some values which I want to be together are get separated using `split()`. Below is my example.

I have string as `"Ambala Cantt. 1.2 Bitter Gourd 1200 2000 1500"` and after splitting it I want it to be as `[Ambala Cantt.,1.2,Bitter Gourd,1200,2000,1500]` but I am getting the result as `['Ambala', 'Cantt.', '1.2', 'Bitter', 'Gourd', '1200', '2000', '1500']`. Which is what I don't want it to be.

Why I am using `split()` because I have to convert my string into list so that I can stored each data into my database. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this or some better way to convert my string into list.

Comment: Do you have any reproduceable logic that determines how to split the string? Maybe something to do with the numbers in your string?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're trying to parse results for Mandi pricing from [http://agmarknet.nic.in/](http://agmarknet.nic.in/cmm2_home.asp?comm=Bitter%20gourd&dt=12/09/2015). These have a predictable pattern.

```
example = "Ambala Cantt. 1.2 Bitter Gourd 1200 2000 1500"
print([c.strip() for c in re.match(r"""
    (?P<market>[^0-9]+)
    (?P<arrivals>[^ ]+)
    (?P<variety>[^0-9]+)
    (?P<min>[0-9]+)
    \ (?P<max>[0-9]+)
    \ (?P<modal>[0-9]+)""",
    example,
    re.VERBOSE
).groups()])
['Ambala Cantt.', '1.2', 'Bitter Gourd', '1200', '2000', '1500']
```

Comment: I am very much surprised that how cum u came to know what exactly i am doing.Yes,this is  what i am trying to do(parsing results from mandi pricing and from the same url http://agmarknet.nic.in/). Thanks for resolving this.It worked 100%.

Comment: Can you please explain me what actually you did in this?.Not much aware of the keywords you used in the solution and it will be of great help for me in future.

Comment: Research how [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) work and in particular the [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module in python. This is handy to know for a wide variety of problems. If this answer worked for you, please mark it as the answer :)

Comment: I am creating my app using google appengine and i am getting below error:  re.VERBOSE
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'.I tried importing "import re" but didn't worked in google appnegine but if i am writing a sample program in notepad using "import re",i got the correct output.Is 're' a third party module.?.How i can import it in google appnengine.?

Comment: Above solution does not work if put in for each loop.

Answer (score 1):

Need to find a consistent pattern in the input (I'm assuming there are a lot of strings with inconsistent delimiters in this dataset)--possibly use a regex to perform the split: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

[OpenRefine](http://openrefine.org/) could facilitate data scrubbing the strings if they are from an input file.